# Find $f'(x)$ if $f(x) = g(t +x)$ and if $f(t) = g(t+x)$. Spivak - Ch 9 - Q.10

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This question is from *Spivak's Calculus*:

Find $f'(x)$ if $f(x) = g(t +x)$ and if $f(t) = g(t+x)$

I'm not really seeing how the author made the jump to the conclusion in the solution to the second part of the question: Here is the solution to the question:

[image]

So I did establish a few questions before that $f'(x) = g'(t+x)$ (which is problem 8a that is referenced to). But I don't see how he is able to conclude $f'(x) = g'(2x)$?

Comment: Set $t=x$. ${}{}$

Comment: Ok so I do see that this works, but what is the purpose of this question then? Trying to see what is the author trying to imply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moral of this exercise: Pay attention to how $f$ is defined, specifically what is a variable and what is a constant.

The question is asking you to evaluate $f'$ at $x$ under two scenarios, where in each scenario $f$ is defined in terms of some other function $g$.

1. $f(x)=g(t+x)$. Here we write $f$ as a function of the variable $x$, and we can only assume that $t$ is a constant. In that case $f'(x)=g'(t+x)$ for all $x$, by the chain rule.
2. $f(t)=g(t+x)$. Here $f$ is a function of the variable $t$ and we assume $x$ is a constant. By the chain rule, $f'(t) = g'(t+x)$ for all $t$. The RHS is the same as in the previous scenario, but note that $f'$ is a function of $t$, not $x$. Therefore $f'(x)$ must mean "evaluate $f'$ at the constant $x$".

Comment: Hmmmm...are you saying something like: $f'(x) = g'(x+t) = f'(t) \rightarrow x = t \rightarrow f'(x) = g'(2x)$? I did get the idea of the function being evaluated as $x$ is the variable and $t$ is the variable for their respective situations, but going about it formally is confusing.

Comment: @dc3rd The two scenarios are non-overlapping. The $f$ seen in scenario 1 shouldn't be used in scenario 2. To avoid confusion it would be clearer to write scenario 2 as "$h(t) = g(t+x)$, therefore $h'(t)=g'(t+x)$, therefore $h'(x)=g'(x+x)$. That way you aren't led to equate the $x$ in scenario 1 with the $t$ in scenario 2.